# Problem with an asp net password regular expression?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm trying to validate the following in a password field:
-at least 1 alpha
-at least 1 numeric
-at least 1 special (non alphanumeric)

My reg exp is this:

```
Regex.IsMatch("jpere33z@1?hs", @"^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\W*)\w*$")
```

and it says it is not valid. The `\W` part is what is not working.

Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w*$` will only match letters, numbers, and underscore.  This is what you want:

```
Regex.IsMatch("@1?hsjpere33z", @"^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?\W).*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

I moved the validation to the left, and added `\w*` right before the `\W`.
Edit: Also used `.*` instead of `\w` for test lookaheads.

Comment: Hi @Mat it works.. but only if they are in the specified order... I need they to be in any order... do you have something for that???

Comment: @Rafael, fixed for symbol-first passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't allow more then 1 digit.

Your easiest route would probably be to have 3 regex checks, one for the existance of each character type.

Comment: The regex allows for any number of digits (at least 1) because `\w` matches digits, letters, and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do with regex (at least only one). In the regex you are giving the fields an order, so the parser expects them in that order.

One alternative would be to use a choice, but that would make difficult to check that you have one of each of the terms:

```
[\w|\d|\W]{4,}
```

If you want to use regex, check three of them:

1) Is there a digit?

2) Is there a character?

3) Is there a special?

If all of them are true.... bingo!